# Getting all the UI elements of the current screen in UI testing or Unit tests

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing, xcode-ui-testing

I am new to iOS and writing a UI test case for a screen. The thing is, I want to write such a test case where I want to test same behavior for a particular type of UIElement (for eg, same behavior for button type). So instead of writing tests for different screens I wanted to know if there's some way in XCUI or any other framework where we can get all UIElements present on the screen in some data structure. 
Thanks

Comment: What do you want to test for example? With UI testing you access an element and then assert what you expect. So, for example; If you have a list of `accessibilityIds` (or labels) for elements that you expect to be there, and you can assert their existence iterating over the list.

Comment: I am trying to implement accessibility test using XCUI framework for my sample application and there are multiple screens and I want to avoid writing tests for each screen. I just want one test for all screens.

Comment: How do you define which elements should be there for each screen? For example; if you have a list of titles of the buttons, you can assert their existence like `app.buttons["button1"]` Otherwise you can not iterate over `app.buttons`

Answer (score 2):

You can get such data (elements, their labels, types, and other properties) with `snapshot()` method. You will get a tree of `XCUIElementSnapshot`. Also, you can get a dictionary representation.

Start reading documentation from here

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementsnapshotproviding